# e.force:refreshView not working in combination with e.force:closeQuickAction

Tags: aura, quickaction

I haven LWC modal popup initiated by a Quick Action. For this some Aura code is needed, but I have that working.

Upon closing (via a button on the modal popup), the underlying record page should be updated (refreshed). But it's not. The modal popup closes, but the page is not updated. This is my Javascript:

```
({
  modalClose : function(component, event) {
    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
  }
})
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have any component on the page? If yes, please check if the refresh event is handled

Comment: Doesn't changing the order of the events work? I would imagine if you refresh the view before closing the modal, that should work.

Comment: Changing of the order of the events does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try standard Js way

```
window.location.reload()
```

Comment: This indeed refreshes the page, but it is a bit drastic. I am looking for something more subtle. Like what you get when you are on an Account page and add a new Contact. After saving the new Contact, the Account page is refreshed, but much more inobtrustive. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: From my experience, it works smoothly not everywhere. can you check if you are seeing any error in console?

Comment: No, there are no errors in the console.